# tcl regsub will not work

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to write an extremely simple piece of code and tcl is not cooperating. I can only imagine there is a very simple error I am missing in my code but I have absolutely no idea what it could be please help I'm so frustrated!!

My code is the following ...

```
proc substitution {stringToSub} {
   set afterSub $stringToSub
   regsub {^.*?/projects} "$stringToSub" "//Path/projects" afterSub
   regsub {C:/projects} "$stringToSub" "//Path/projects" afterSub
   return $afterSub
}

puts "[substitution /projects] "
puts "[substitution C:/projects] "
```

The substitution works fine for the second expression  but not the first one. Why is that??
I have also tried using

```
regsub {^/projects} "$stringToSub" "//Path/projects" afterSub
```

and

```
regsub {/projects} "$stringToSub" "//Path/projects" afterSub
```

but neither are working. What is going on??

Comment: When you say "works fine for the second expression" are you referring to the second `regsub` call within the `substitution` proc or are you referring to the second invocation of the `subsitution` method? Also, in the case where it "doesn't work" what result are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: I supposed I mean both. When I use
puts "[substitution C:/projects] " 
the output is "//Path/projects", which is what I want. However, when I use
puts "[substitution /projects] " the output is "/projects" so the substitution that I want is not occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Since yours two regsub calls don't change the input string (i.e.: `$stringToSub`) but put the result in the string `$afterSub` which is returned by the function. You will always obtain the result of the last `regsub` call and the result of the first `regsub` call in `$aftersub` is always overwritten.

Note that the first pattern is more general and include all the strings matched by the second (assuming that `$stringToSub` is always a path). If you hope to obtain `"//Path/projects"` for your sample strings, you can simply remove the second regsub call:

```
proc substitution {stringToSub} {
    set afterSub $stringToSub
    regsub {^.*?/projects} "$stringToSub" "//Path/projects" afterSub
    return $afterSub
}
```

Comment: Why do we need a `?` in `{^.*?/projects}`? Anyway `.*` matches zero or more occurrences right? As I understand `?` is for matching 0/1 occurrences of the previous character.

Comment: `.*?` switches the match to non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines in your procedure will effectively do nothing, since `regsub` always overwrites the destination variable (`afterSub`) even when there's 0 matches/substitutions made. From the [regsub manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm):

> This command matches the regular expression *exp* against *string*, and either copies *string* to the variable whose name is given by *varName* or returns *string* if *varName* is not present. (Regular expression matching is described in the **[re_syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)** reference page.) If there is a match, then while copying *string* to *varName* (or to the result of this command if *varName* is not present) the portion of *string* that matched *exp* is replaced with *subSpec*.

There's no need to match `C:/projects` specifically, because `^.*?/projects` will match that text?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your second use of the `regsub` operation is overwriting the substituted value from the first `regsub` use.

We could simplify the code to just this:

```tcl
proc substitution {stringToSub} {
    return [regsub {^.*?/projects} $stringToSub "//Path/projects"]
}
```